# View manual file growth events

Tags: file, sql-server-2014, tempdb

My tempdb data file has grown significantly in size and I'd like to get an understanding of who made the change, this is a fairly recent event and there are no autogrowth events in the disk usage reports so it would suggest that the file was grown manually. My question was, is it possible to find out when a file was last manually grown and if so by what increment?

Comment: Fairly recent could still mean that the default trace used to track auto-growth events doesn't have the event stored. So, maybe it was auto if it's a pretty busy server. This is where auditing comes in. However, i'd ask this on dba.stackexchange.com. You're more likely to get a good answer for this question over there.